# What modifications will lead to size reduction of binary size in C++ code

Tags: c++, templates

I have been working on very big code base of C++ project. There are about 2k files and comprising about 200k lines of code.
The code includes heavy usage of templates
There is lot of inlining in code
Currently using clang++ with O2 option for compiling
The final executable size is about 50 MB

For some reason, I want to reduce the binary size still further.
Steps already taken
1> Replace templates with non-template code where possible
2> Replace XML library from xerces to expat

Any suggestions in this regard are welcome

Comment: Did you try to compile it using the just released GCC 4.8 with `-flto -Os` (link time optimization, optimize for size) ?

Comment: You might be able to compress the compiled binary with [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: And you did strip the debug data, didn't you?

Comment: @Basile, cannot use Os because it because the resultant performance will be less than O2, and we do not want to compromise on that

Comment: @rodrigo, yes all debug symbols are stripped

Comment: @uttam is that an expectation or did you really measure that -Os performance is noticeably worse than -O2?

Comment: Reducing the code size can reduce the instruction-cache footprint and thus increase the program execution speed, so your expectation is flawed unless backed up by real numbers.

Comment: BTW, concerning C++, there is usually a diagnostic mode for the runtime library, in particular the parts coming from the STL. This causes runtime overhead in both speed and size.

Comment: Are you so sure that `-flto -Os` gives slower code than `-O2` ? Did you benchmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following methods are commonly used to reduce the size of programs,

1. Use your compiler specific Techniques to reduce the size.
2. Compile using `gcc -S program.c` to get the Assembler file. You can now perform assembler based space optimizations.
3. Reduce the number of global variables in C.
4. Instead of complex algorithms which gives you very small changes in the execution time, use simple algorithms. For example use `bubble sort` instead of `Merge sort` if the number of elements in the list is not very large.
5. Remove simple functions which are used just once or twice.
6. Eliminate dead code. Many often in large projects there are some.
7. Be careful about the library functions you include in your program.

Comment: Adding to 4., I'd like to point out that using a map<> with its internal tree and O(log n) lookup time can be slower than using a vector<> with O(n) lookup time, which is the case when the number of elements is low. Remember the first part of every complexity spec: "There is an n > n_0 for which ..."! In other words it's not just algorithms but also data types.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run `strip` on the finished executable to remove debugging information (n.b. you can keep the unstripped file too in case you later need the debugging info).
2. Make sure you link system-provided libraries dynamically, not statically.
3. Move nontrivial functions from header files to .cpp files (can even apply to some template functions, if they're only used in the same .cpp file as an implementation detail for example).
4. Hunt down and eliminate dead code.  Many projects have quite a bit of this.  Consider using a code coverage analyzer to help you find candidates for removal.  Hopefully you have some tests to help.
5. Consider compressing the actual binary.  How big is it if you run it through gzip or bzip2?

Comment: For the dead code, try using GCC and LD's options for putting all functions in their own section, and then dropping all sections without reference indirectly from main().

Answer (score 1):

[UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) is a good tool for reducing the size of executables. It supports many platforms and executable formats.

The executable is decompressed on startup, and the code for doing so is included in the executable itself. The performance loss is minimal.